# how to add query parameters to router.get

Tags: node.js, express

Environment: MEAN tech stack

Hi, I want to add a query parameter to my router.get but I'm not sure how to define it.

Works like this right now:

```
http://test.com/path1/path2/1

router.get('/path1/path2/:userId', (req, res) => {
    let route = `GET /path1/path2/${req.params.userId}`;
```

I just want to add a search query parameter, would it be something like this?

```
http://test.com/path1/path2/1?q=test
```

And how would that get defined in the router.get?

Comment: It doesn't, it doesn't change the actual route. Did the request not arrive when you tried it?

Comment: I'm still digging through the code and haven't made it that far yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to add a query parameter to your route directly. Just keep `/path1/path2/:userId`.

Within your function you can then check, if a [query parameter](http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.query) exists, here via `req.query.q`.

```
// http://test.com/path1/path2/1?q=test
router.get('/path1/path2/:userId', (req, res) => {
    let route = `GET /path1/path2/${req.params.userId}`;

    // If http://test.com/path1/path2/1, req.query.q is undefined
    console.log(req.params.userId, req.query.q);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the `req.query` object to get query parameters.

So, for the URL `http://test.com/path1/path2/1?q=test`, you could get the query parameter like this:

```
router.get('/path1/path2/:userId', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.userId);        // "1"
    console.log(req.query.q);              // "test"
});
```

Doc for `req.query` is [here](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query).

Answer (score 1):

For this url `http://test.com/path1/path2/1?q=test`

access path params = `req.params.userId`.

access query params = `req.query.q`.

Read more from Express documentation

http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.query

http://expressjs.com/de/api.html#req.params